Is the libsnark library compatible with the arm-none-eabi toolchain for ARM Cortex-M microcontrollers?
I am currently working on a project that involves implementing cryptographic protocols on ARM Cortex-M microcontrollers, specifically the Raspberry Pi Pico (RP2040). I am interested in using the libsnark library for this purpose. However, I need to know if libsnark is compatible with the arm-none-eabi toolchain, which is used for cross-compiling for bare metal environments.
Details:
Target Architecture: ARM Cortex-M (e.g., RP2040 on Raspberry Pi Pico)
Toolchain: ARM GCC (arm-none-eabi-gcc)
Operating System: None (Bare metal)
Questions:
1/ Is the libsnark library compatible with the arm-none-eabi toolchain?
2/ If not currently compatible, are there any known modifications or workarounds to make it work?
I attempted to cross-compile libsnark using the arm-none-eabi toolchain but was unsuccessful. Additionally, I have made an issue on the libsnark GitHub repository to inquire about this compatibility.


1/ Is the libsnark library compatible with the arm-none-eabi toolchain?

I strongly suspect it is not compatible on bare metal ARM without a fair amount of work.
Just checking, have you read the libsnark portability section? It shows points that rely on Linux syscalls and a file system:


Random-number generation is done by reading from /dev/urandom, which is specific to Unix-like systems.


Points 7. and 8. refer to some libraries that only compile on i686 and x86-64 (not ARM), maybe there are command flags to turn that off. This issue makes it seem like someone else was interested in building libsnark for 32 bit arm.

2/ If not currently compatible, are there any known modifications or workarounds to make it work?

You might check for public forks of the github repo that try to port libsnark to bare metal. I took a quick look at the public forks and issues, and it looks like you're the first one trying to do this.
